# setLength change type of TBoundArray when setLength(arr[i]

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I can't compile this peace of code. Why?
on compile get
E2010 Incompatible types: 'TBoundArray' and 'Array'

Code trying to change incoming array by pushing to each dimension in the end of subArray the same value+10000.

```
function Tpt.T(var arr: array of TBoundArray): TBoundArray;
var
  i:Integer;
  j:Integer;
  size:Integer;
  const movObjInd: Integer = 10000;
begin
  for i := Integer(0) to Length(arr) do
  begin
  size:= Length(arr);
  setLength(arr[i],(Length(arr[i])+1)*2);

  j:=0;
    while j < size+1 do
    begin
      if arr[i][j] = 0 then
      begin
        inc(size);
        Continue;
      end;

      Inc(size);
      arr[i][size]:= arr[i][j] + movObjInd;
    end;
  end;
  result:= arr;
end;
```

Comment: Your for loop accesses out of bounds on its final iteration.

Comment: I suspect the `while` loop also has bounds issues, too. I think `size:= Length(arr)` should be `size:= Length(arr[i])`

Comment: Yes, it has problems, i've solved them after I can compile it

`procedure TRptZakaz_AL.addTransObjs(var arr: array of TBoundArray);
var
  i:Integer;
  j:Integer;
  size:Integer;
  const movObjInd: Integer = 10000;
begin
  for i := 0 to Length(arr)-1 do
  begin
  if arr[i][0] = 0 then
  Continue;

  size:= Length(arr[i]);
  setLength(arr[i],size*2);

  j:=0;
    while j < size do
    begin
      if arr[i][j] = 0 then
      begin
        inc(j);
        Continue;
      end;
      arr[i][size+j]:= arr[i][j] + movObjInd;
      Inc(j);
    end;
  end;
end;
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result:= arr;` is trying to assign an **open array** of `TBoundArray` elements to a single `TBoundArray`. That will not work, which is why you get the error.

Since you are directly modifying the elements of the `arr` array, there is no need to return any of them via the function's `Result`. So you should change it into a `procedure` instead.